# Android 4.3 BLE how to write Characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Followed [sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

I know:

- How to read Characteristic value.

But I don't know:

- How to write data to the firmware.

I tried several times, but it did not work.

This is the coding:

```
if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                System.out.println("read!!!!!!");
                // If there is an active notification on a characteristic,
                // clear
                // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user
                // interface.
                if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                            mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                    mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                }
                mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            }
            if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                System.out.println("notify!!!!!!");
                mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                        characteristic, true);
            }
            if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
                if (SampleGattAttributes.AppConfigToBongCharacteristicUUID
                        .equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                    System.out.println("write!!!!!!");
                    mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
                }
            }



public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    if (UUID_SEND_CONFIG_TO_BONG.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {

        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        String data_date_y = String.format("%4s", date.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                .replace(' ', '0');
        String data_date_m = String.format("%2s", date.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                .replace(' ', '0');
        String data_date_d = String.format("%2s", date.get(Calendar.DATE))
                .replace(' ', '0');
        String data_date_h = String.format("%2s", date.get(Calendar.HOUR))
                .replace(' ', '0');
        String data_date_min = String.format("%2s",
                date.get(Calendar.MINUTE)).replace(' ', '0');

        data.append("10FFFF");
        data.append(data_date_y);
        data.append(data_date_m);
        data.append(data_date_d);
        data.append(data_date_h);
        data.append(data_date_min);
        System.out.println(data);
        byte[] dataByte = data.toString().getBytes();

        characteristic.setValue(dataByte);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

}
```

//onCharacteristicWrite()  Not being called

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        System.out.println("writeCharacteristic111");
        System.out.println("status:" + status);
        System.out.println(BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS);
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a quick note, not sure it addresses your issue - but per this bug report (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58979), the sample code you are using is incorrect: the bitwise check "|" should be "&". So if your attribute does not support any of the properties you're checking for, it will still appear that it does. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

I think jkraybill has got the answer for you.

I was using google's bluetooth le sample code, which checks properties bit with '|' operation as following:

```
if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
    ...
}
```

But when I looked into BluetoothGatt code itself, I found it's using '&' operation instead.

```
public boolean writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) == 0
        && (characteristic.getProperties() &
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) == 0) return false;

    ...
}
```

So obviously the sample code was incorrect, if you check further on its definition on Google develop doc: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the value that you would like to write.
you can find what you need in this [example](https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt/DeviceControlActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I wrote to get to write to a characteristic, its rudimentary though but it works especially for unknown UUIDs:

```
public void getACharXandWriteToIt(int value, ScanResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "This is result:: " + result.toString());
    List<ParcelUuid> serviceUUIDs = result.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids();
    ArrayList<BluetoothGattService> services = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics;

    ArrayList<UUID> uuidServiceList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ParcelUuid pUUIDx : serviceUUIDs){
         uuidServiceList.add(pUUIDx.getUuid());
       Log.i(TAG, uuidServiceList.toString());
    }
    for (UUID serviceUUIDx: uuidServiceList){
        Log.i(TAG, "services are: "+ serviceUUIDx.toString());
        MyLogData +="services are: "+ serviceUUIDx.toString()+"\n";
        BluetoothGattService service = bleGatt.getService(serviceUUIDx);
        if (service!=null) {
            characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
            services.add(service);
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
                if(characteristic!=null){
                    Log.i(TAG, "CharX:: " + characteristic.toString());
                    MyLogData += "CharX:: " + characteristic.toString()+"\n";
                    Log.i(TAG, "Charx UUID:: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                    MyLogData += "Charx UUID:: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Charx write type:: " + characteristic.getProperties());
                  /*  Log.i(TAG, "Write no response:: " +
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Write:: " +
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Notify:: " +
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Read:: " +
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ);*/
                    if (characteristic.getWriteType() == 1){
                        MyLogData += "Write data: " + value + "\n";
                        characteristic.setValue(value,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SINT8, 0);
                        writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It also allows u to get Service UUIDs and Characteristic UUID and properties and write type, i could go on and on, it is tedious but fairly efficient.